# setTimeout() function stops scrolling

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created a simple chat app . I have used `setTimeout` to refresh the messages every .5 ms and `scrolltop` to keep the scroll bar at the bottom.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
       <html>  
       <head>  
       <title>Live Table Data Edit</title>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    />  
        <script 
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <div class="container">  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <h3 align="center">You Are : <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></h3><br />  
                     <div id="live_data"></div>                 
                </div>  
            <div id="messages" style="    border: 1px solid #ccc;
         width: 350px;
height: 210px;
padding: 10px;
overflow-y:scroll;
display:none;"></div> 
            <div class="area" style="display:none">
            <textarea id="text" name="text"style="    border: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 350px;
height: 50px;
padding: 10px;" ></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub" value="Send" />
                </div>
           </div>  


<script>
var currentID = null;
var chatTimer = null;

function fetch_data() {
$.ajax({
url: "select.php",
method: "POST",
success: function(data) {
  $('#live_data').html(data);
  //fetch_chat();
    }
  });
}

function fetch_chat() {
$.ajax({
url: "fetch_chat.php",
method: "POST",
data: {
  id: currentID
},
dataType: "text",
success: function(data) {
  $("#messages").show();
  $('#messages').html(data);
  $("div.area").show();

  $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
  return false;
   chatTimer = setTimeout(fetch_chat, 500); //request the chat again in 2 seconds time     
    }

  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
   currentID = $(this).data("id1");
   //immediately fetch chat for the new ID, and clear any waiting fetch 
     timer that might be pending
   clearTimeout(chatTimer);
   fetch_chat(); 
 });

$("#sub").click(function() {
var text = $("#text").val();

$.post('insert_chat.php', {
  id: currentID,
  msg: text
 }, function(data) {
  $("#messages").append(data);
  $("#text").val('');
  });
});

fetch_data();//this will also trigger the first fetch_chat once it completes
   });
   </script>
  </body>  
  </html>
```

everything works fine as accordance to my need but when I use `setTimeout()` {as I m using it right now} the scrolling gets stuck and when I remove `setTimeout` scrolling part work fine but the other user cant see the new messages in real time as it is not refreshing in their side.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is behaving as expected. Every 5ms it sets the scroll to the top. This effectively negates any attempt by the user to scroll, as every 5ms the scroll gets reset.

A few options:

use a div with fixed size to hold your chat and then manage the contents accordingly.

Make it so that you only update​ the scroll if there are new messages. You can do this via etags or by caching the last message and verifying that the next request has the same last message.